# Adjoints of normal transformations on real inner product spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations, inner-products, adjoint-operators

Can someone please check me on the following result and proof?

Let $E$ be a non-zero finite-dimensional inner product space over $\mathbb{R}$. A linear transformation $\varphi:E\to E$ is normal if and only if its adjoint $\varphi^*$ can be written in the form $\varphi^*=f(\varphi)$ for some polynomial $f\in\mathbb{R}[t]$.

*Proof:*
If $\varphi^*=f(\varphi)$, then $\varphi^*\varphi=\varphi\varphi^*$, so $\varphi$ is normal. Conversely, if $\varphi$ is normal let
$$E=E_1\oplus\cdots\oplus E_r\tag{1}$$
be the generalized eigenspace decomposition of $E$ under $\varphi$ and $\varphi_i:E_i\to E_i$ the induced restriction. Since $\varphi$ is normal, (1) is an orthogonal decomposition and $\varphi_i$ is a scalar multiple of an isometry (see [1], p. 437).

Write $\varphi_i=\lambda_i\tau_i$ where $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\tau_i$ is an isometry. We know $(\tau_i)^*=\tau_i^{-1}=f_i(\tau_i)$ for some $f_i\in\mathbb{R}[t]$. Since (1) is orthogonal, we have the direct sum
$$\varphi^*=\sum(\varphi_i)^*=\sum\lambda_i(\tau_i)^*=\sum\lambda_i f_i(\tau_i)\tag{2}$$
Define $g_i\in\mathbb{R}[t]$ by
$$g_i(t)=\begin{cases}
0&\text{if }\lambda_i=0\\
\lambda_if_i(\lambda_i^{-1}t)&\text{if }\lambda_i\ne0
\end{cases}$$
Let $\pi_i$ be the $i$-th projection operator for (1). Then $\pi_i=h_i(\varphi)$ for some $h_i\in\mathbb{R}[t]$. It follows from (2) that
$$\varphi^*=\sum g_i(\varphi)h_i(\varphi)$$
Setting $f=\sum g_ih_i$, we have $\varphi^*=f(\varphi)$.

**Note:** I know that the result is true in the complex case but I am interested in the real case.

**References:**

1. Greub, W. *Linear Algebra*, 4th ed. Springer, 1975.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof works.  Alternatively, you can simply derive the real case from the complex case.  Complexifying $E$, by the complex case (which is an immediate consequence of the spectral theorem for normal operators and Lagrange interpolation) there is a polynomial $g\in\mathbb{C}[t]$ such that $\varphi^*=g(\varphi)$.  Now let us pick a basis for $E$, so we can represent $\varphi$ as a matrix with real entries.  Note that since $\varphi$ and $\varphi^*$ have real entries, we have $$\varphi^*=\overline{\varphi^*}=\overline{g}(\overline{\varphi})=\overline{g}(\varphi)$$ as well.  Here the overline on a matrix denotes entrywise complex conjugation, and $\overline{g}$ is the polynomial obtained by conjugating each coefficient of $g$.  We thus have $$\varphi^*=\frac{g(\varphi)+\overline{g}(\varphi)}{2},$$ i.e. $\varphi^*=f(\varphi)$ where $f=\frac{g+\overline{g}}{2}$ is a polynomial with real coefficients.

(Or alternatively, instead of thinking in terms of conjugating matrices, you can note that $g$ is chosen such that $g(a)=\overline{a}$ for each complex eigenvalue $a$ of $\varphi$.  Now for each such $a$, $\overline{a}$ is also an eigenvalue of $\varphi$.  Thus $g(\overline{a})=a$ so $\overline{g}(a)=\overline{g(\overline{a})}=\overline{a}$.  That is, $\overline{g}$ also conjugates each eigenvalue of $\varphi$ and thus so does $\frac{g+\overline{g}}{2}$, which has real coefficients.)